# Popup never loses focus

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I'm having a problem with my popup. When the user clicks the profile, I want to display a popup.
This already works but the popup doesn't close when it loses focus.

I've tried to set the stayopen property to false but then the popup shows up for about half a second and then immediately closes.

I also tried to catch the focus lost event in code, but the event never triggers...

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:UserControlSolution.Converter"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="UserControlSolution.ProfileControl"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
Height="55">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:ConnectedStatusToColorConverter x:Key="ConnectedStatusToColorConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="ProfileOptionsStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,3,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14.5" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectGrey}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Canvas x:Key="Lynx_logo_NoText" x:Name="Lynx_logo_NoText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="189.333" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="504.864">
        <Canvas x:Name="Laag_2" Height="156.803" Canvas.Left="26.033" Canvas.Top="16.47" Width="450.509">
            <Path Data="F1M140.0616,111.5394L140.0616,168.4354C140.0616,169.0754,139.9016,169.6314,139.5826,170.1064C139.2646,170.5874,138.7136,170.9654,137.9206,171.2384C137.1316,171.5194,136.0656,171.7644,134.7216,171.9584C133.3746,172.1524,131.7546,172.2564,129.8586,172.2564C127.8856,172.2564,126.2406,172.1524,124.9396,171.9584C123.6336,171.7644,122.5656,171.5194,121.7336,171.2384C120.9056,170.9654,120.3296,170.5874,120.0126,170.1064C119.6986,169.6314,119.5416,169.0754,119.5416,168.4354L119.5416,111.5394L93.9836,56.1284C93.1016,54.3004,92.5696,52.8684,92.3686,51.8324C92.1686,50.8104,92.3686,50.0044,92.9656,49.4514C93.5616,48.8954,94.6346,48.5374,96.1866,48.3784C97.7356,48.2214,99.8216,48.1414,102.4466,48.1414C104.8326,48.1414,106.7586,48.2214,108.2336,48.3784C109.7056,48.5374,110.8746,48.7554,111.7496,49.0294C112.6246,49.3174,113.2846,49.7144,113.7196,50.2254C114.1536,50.7424,114.5736,51.4014,114.9756,52.1934C114.9756,52.1934,128.1596,87.4004,130.2146,92.0934L130.4496,92.0934C132.2656,87.5664,134.1506,83.0514,136.0836,78.5604C138.0196,74.0694,139.9816,69.6334,141.9666,65.2574C141.9666,65.2574,164.0146,19.1754,164.4506,18.6164C164.8886,18.0634,165.4816,17.6464,166.2436,17.3654C166.9976,17.0844,168.0476,16.8684,169.4056,16.7064C170.7566,16.5504,172.4606,16.4704,174.5306,16.4704C177.3946,16.4704,179.6426,16.5734,181.2716,16.7684C182.8956,16.9674,184.0326,17.3474,184.6716,17.9014C185.3096,18.4604,185.5226,19.2544,185.3286,20.2884C185.1266,21.3194,184.5926,22.7164,183.7176,24.4624z" Fill="#FF646363" Height="155.786" Canvas.Left="66.261" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="93.104"/>
            <Path Data="M468.9649,21.5218C470.5999,20.1588,471.8999,19.3438,472.8649,19.0808C473.8309,18.8198,474.5919,19.1598,475.1489,20.1048C475.7059,21.0488,476.0769,22.5998,476.2629,24.7498C476.4469,26.9018,476.5419,29.7638,476.5419,33.3308C476.5419,36.6918,476.4849,39.3148,476.3739,41.2048C476.2629,43.0938,476.0579,44.5898,475.7619,45.6918C475.4659,46.7938,475.1119,47.6358,474.7029,48.2108C474.2959,48.7898,473.7559,49.2888,473.0879,49.7068L415.7079,95.0558L473.0879,140.8758C473.7559,141.4028,474.3139,141.9788,474.7589,142.6088C475.2039,143.2388,475.5579,144.1038,475.8169,145.2058C476.0769,146.3088,476.2629,147.8048,476.3739,149.6938C476.4849,151.5828,476.5419,154.1028,476.5419,157.2518C476.5419,160.7158,476.4469,163.4478,476.2629,165.4398C476.0769,167.4358,475.7059,168.8258,475.1489,169.6128C474.5919,170.3998,473.8309,170.6638,472.8649,170.3998C471.8999,170.1388,470.5999,169.3248,468.9649,167.9588L402.6729,112.3758L338.6079,165.4398C336.9759,166.6998,335.6559,167.5138,334.6529,167.8808C333.6499,168.2508,332.8699,168.0138,332.3139,167.1718C331.7559,166.3328,331.4039,164.8648,331.2549,162.7628C331.1069,160.6648,331.0319,157.7788,331.0319,154.1028C331.0319,150.9538,331.0879,148.3828,331.1989,146.3868C331.3109,144.3948,331.4969,142.8198,331.7559,141.6638C332.0179,140.5098,332.3879,139.6708,332.8699,139.1438C333.3549,138.6208,333.8929,138.0418,334.4859,137.4128L388.4109,93.6378L334.4859,50.1798C333.8929,49.6558,333.3549,49.1308,332.8699,48.6048C332.3879,48.0808,332.0179,47.3208,331.7559,46.3218C331.4969,45.3248,331.3109,43.9348,331.1989,42.1488C331.0879,40.3648,331.0319,37.9518,331.0319,34.9058C331.0319,31.6528,331.1259,29.0008,331.3109,26.9538C331.4969,24.9068,331.8509,23.4388,332.3689,22.5448C332.8899,21.6548,333.6499,21.3118,334.6529,21.5218C335.6559,21.7328,336.9759,22.4668,338.6079,23.7258L402.2269,76.6328L468.9649,21.5218z" 
                  Height="158.784" Canvas.Left="301.359" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="{Binding mainViewModel.IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource ConnectedStatusToColorConverter}}" StrokeThickness="7.281" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Canvas.Top="-1.115" Width="152.791"/>
            <Path Data="F1M106.0738,163.4183C106.0738,165.0103,105.9928,166.3413,105.8348,167.4143C105.6748,168.4873,105.4178,169.4023,105.0598,170.1573C104.7018,170.9143,104.2638,171.4703,103.7478,171.8273C103.2298,172.1863,102.6138,172.3643,101.8988,172.3643L33.6678,172.3643C31.8368,172.3643,30.1078,171.7493,28.4788,170.5163C26.8478,169.2833,26.0328,167.1153,26.0328,164.0153L26.0328,21.1113C26.0328,20.4753,26.1918,19.9183,26.5098,19.4413C26.8268,18.9633,27.3848,18.5873,28.1798,18.3083C28.9738,18.0303,30.0478,17.7913,31.4008,17.5923C32.7528,17.3943,34.3828,17.2933,36.2918,17.2933C38.2788,17.2933,39.9298,17.3943,41.2418,17.5923C42.5538,17.7913,43.6078,18.0303,44.4028,18.3083C45.1968,18.5873,45.7548,18.9633,46.0728,19.4413C46.3898,19.9183,46.5508,20.4753,46.5508,21.1113L46.5508,154.5913L101.8988,154.5913C102.6138,154.5913,103.2298,154.7703,103.7478,155.1283C104.2638,155.4853,104.7018,156.0043,105.0598,156.6793C105.4178,157.3543,105.6748,158.2493,105.8348,159.3623C105.9928,160.4773,106.0738,161.8283,106.0738,163.4183" Fill="#FF646363" Height="155.071" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0.823" Width="80.041"/>
            <Path Data="F1M312.2998,164.0872C312.2998,165.6792,312.0318,167.0302,311.4988,168.1442C310.9638,169.2582,310.2648,170.1712,309.4018,170.8872C308.5378,171.6032,307.5708,172.1202,306.5028,172.4382C305.4328,172.7542,304.3638,172.9142,303.2938,172.9142L296.5108,172.9142C294.3698,172.9142,292.4988,172.6942,290.8958,172.2592C289.2918,171.8222,287.7708,171.0262,286.3308,169.8732C284.8938,168.7212,283.4518,167.1502,282.0128,165.1612C280.5748,163.1742,279.0458,160.6282,277.4328,157.5262L230.3438,69.7332C227.8818,65.2002,225.4018,60.4492,222.8998,55.4782C220.3988,50.5092,218.0728,45.6782,215.9178,40.9852L215.6798,40.9852C215.8378,46.7112,215.9568,52.5562,216.0378,58.5202C216.1158,64.4842,216.1568,70.4092,216.1568,76.2932L216.1568,169.4552C216.1568,170.0132,215.9888,170.5492,215.6538,171.0662C215.3178,171.5842,214.7518,171.9812,213.9538,172.2592C213.1558,172.5382,212.1088,172.7752,210.8078,172.9752C209.5068,173.1722,207.8478,173.2732,205.8348,173.2732C203.8198,173.2732,202.1628,173.1722,200.8618,172.9752C199.5608,172.7752,198.5338,172.5382,197.7788,172.2592C197.0228,171.9812,196.4788,171.5842,196.1428,171.0662C195.8068,170.5492,195.6398,170.0132,195.6398,169.4552L195.6398,27.0292C195.6398,23.8492,196.5418,21.5832,198.3478,20.2302C200.1538,18.8792,202.1238,18.2022,204.2578,18.2022L214.3548,18.2022C216.7328,18.2022,218.7228,18.4012,220.3238,18.7982C221.9248,19.1972,223.3618,19.8532,224.6328,20.7662C225.9038,21.6822,227.1368,22.9552,228.3278,24.5842C229.5168,26.2142,230.7648,28.2632,232.0738,30.7272L268.2728,98.4812C270.5028,102.6162,272.6538,106.6512,274.7298,110.5882C276.8038,114.5242,278.8018,118.4012,280.7238,122.2192C282.6458,126.0352,284.5478,129.7932,286.4308,133.4912C288.3138,137.1892,290.1768,140.9072,292.0228,144.6442L292.1418,144.6442C291.9818,138.3632,291.8818,131.8202,291.8428,125.0222C291.8018,118.2232,291.7838,111.6822,291.7838,105.3992L291.7838,21.6612C291.7838,21.1062,291.9518,20.5882,292.2858,20.1102C292.6218,19.6332,293.1868,19.2162,293.9858,18.8582C294.7818,18.5002,295.8308,18.2432,297.1318,18.0832C298.4328,17.9242,300.1318,17.8442,302.2298,17.8442C304.0748,17.8442,305.6708,17.9242,307.0128,18.0832C308.3548,18.2432,309.4038,18.5002,310.1608,18.8582C310.9148,19.2162,311.4618,19.6332,311.7978,20.1102C312.1318,20.5882,312.2998,21.1062,312.2998,21.6612z" 
                  Fill="#FF646363" Height="155.429" Canvas.Left="169.607" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="1.374" Width="116.66"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="Laag_3"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="HeaderContainer" Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource VeryDarkGrey}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ProfilePanelStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="ProfilePanelMouseEnter">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePanel">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF404040"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="ProfilePanelMouseOut"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ProfilePanelMouseDown">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePanel">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF404040"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserNameTextBlock">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="17.666"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePicture">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="43"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePicture">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="43"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="ProfilePanelMouseUp">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePanel">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF404040"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserNameTextBlock">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="18.667"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePicture">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="45"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProfilePicture">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="45"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox x:Name="LynxLogoContainer" StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform" Height="35" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,0" >
        <ContentControl x:Name="MessageAction" Content="{StaticResource Lynx_logo_NoText}"  Margin="0,5" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Grid x:Name="ProfilePanel" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="ProfilePanel_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="ProfilePanelMouseDown"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="ProfilePanelMouseUp"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="ProfilePanelMouseEnter"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="ProfilePanelMouseOut"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="UserNameTextBlock" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Foreground="Silver" 
                   TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="18.667" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Text="Laurens" />

        <WrapPanel x:Name="ProfilePictureContainer" Grid.Column="1" Width="45" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Image x:Name="ProfilePicture" Source="/Image/JV.jpg" Width="45" Height="45" />
        </WrapPanel>

    </Grid>

    <Popup x:Name="ProfilePopup" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ProfilePictureContainer}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
            MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ProfilePanel}" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=HeaderContainer}" 
            VerticalOffset="2" PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency="True">

        <Border Background="{StaticResource VeryDarkGrey}" BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" BorderBrush="#3C3C3C">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ProfileOptionsStyle}" Text="Status: Online" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ProfileOptionsStyle}" Text="Verander profielfoto" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,3">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#FF4E4E4E" Height="1" Margin="10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ProfileOptionsStyle}" Text="Afsluiten" Margin="5,2,5,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>

</Grid>
```

This is the code where I open the popup

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UserControlSolution
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProfileControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProfileControl : UserControl
    {
        public ProfileControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ProfilePopup.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(ProfilePopup_LostFocus);
        }

        void ProfilePopup_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProfilePopup.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void ProfilePanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ProfilePopup.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by setting the `StaysOpen` property to `false` and `Binding` the `Popup.IsOpen` property to a `bool` property and setting the property to `false` when I need the `Popup` to close. The problem of trying to do this in the `LostFocus` event is that the `Popup` will lose focus even if the user just clicks on a control inside the `Popup`, as *that* control will take the focus... I'm guessing that is why your `Popup` was closing so quickly.

For example, I have a custom `AutoCompleteTextBox` and that closes the `Popup` control in various event handlers after a user have selected one of the suggestions:

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Text = SelectedSuggestion;
    if (SuggestionSelected != null) SuggestionSelected(this, new EventArgs());
    Focus();
    CaretIndex = Text.Length;
    IsPopupOpen = false; // <<< Here is the line that closes the Popup
}
```